# DevExpress MVC GridView Customization Windows in vol 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

Does anyone know how to show Customization Window in DevExpress MVC GridView in version 10.2.8.0 (V2010 vol. 2)?

The MVC examples on DevExpress' website are for 2011 and 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is available starting with version v2011 vol 1 (11.1) only:

[GridView - Provide support for CustomizationWindow](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S35528)

Comment: I found the same information. I just hoped that someone would bring better and more optimistic news :-) Thanks Mikhail!